# Uno Platform app runs perfectly well in Debug but not so well in Release

Tags: uno-platform

I just finished writing an app using the Uno Platform framework.
It works perfectly well in Debug mode but when I run the release version (For Windows), my third-party libraries don't work well.

I have added `<PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>` to the Windows Head .csproj file but I'm still having this issue so I don't think it's the ILLinker that's trimming those libraries out.

How do I fix this?